# Why is my dynamic delete not working?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

The insert and dynamic table creation works fine. Everything does what it is supposed up to deleting a record from the database dynamically by pushing the button on that row. Tried several different ways to access the value with no results. The button just clicks and nothing happens. Any help would be greatly appreciated! ( Code for all four parts are below.)

Main Page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PHP Test</title>
<link href="styleTest.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<header id="header"><strong>PHP Test</strong></header>
<div id="mainContent" align="center">
<form id="myForm" action="insert.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr valign="baseline">
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td> <input id="name" type="text" name="name"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
    <td>Comment:</td>
        <td> <input id="comment" type="text" name="comment"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
        <td><input name="sub" id="sub" type="button" value="Save"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<span id="result"></span>
</div><!-- mainContent -->
</div><!-- Container -->
<script src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="my_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Insert Page:

```
<?php
//get the values passed by post
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);

//create connection to Database
$hostname = "localhost";
$database = "test";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
mysqli_select_db($con,$database);

//Run the insert query and check to see if it processes
if(mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO info VALUES('','$name', '$comment')"))
{
  echo "Successfully Inserted";
  $sql2="SELECT * FROM info ORDER BY ID ASC";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
  echo "<table border='1'>
  <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Comment</th>
  <th>Remove Entry</th>
  </tr>";

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['NAME'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['COMMENTS'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td> <form id='myForm2' method='post' action='delete.php'><input name='del' id='del'
     type='button' value='Delete'><input id='id' type='hidden' name='id' value=".$row['ID']."></form></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
}
else
  echo "Save Failed!";
//close connection to database
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Delete Page:

```
<?php
//create connection to Database
$hostname = "localhost";
$database = "test";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
mysqli_select_db($con,$database);
//retrieve posted variables
$id= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

$sql="DELETE FROM info WHERE ID = $id";
$query = mysql_query($con,$sql);
if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){ 
$sql2="SELECT * FROM info ORDER BY ID ASC";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
  echo "<table border='1'>
  <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Comment</th>
  <th>Remove Entry</th>
  </tr>";

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['NAME'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['COMMENTS'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td> <form id='myForm2 method='post' action='delete.php'><input name='del' id='del' type='button' value='Delete'><input id='id' type='hidden' name='id' value=".$row['ID']."></form></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
}else{
echo "Error deleting Data";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#sub").click( function()
   {
        //Check to see that no fields are left blank if one is all fields are cleared and save is failed from insert.php.
        if ($("#name").val()=="")
        {
            clearInput();
            return false;
        }
        else if($("#comment").val()=="")
        {
            clearInput();
            return false;
        }
        //save the fields into an array and post to the result span then clear inputs   
        $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
        $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
        function(info){ $("#result").html(info);});
        clearInput();  
  });

  $('#del').click(function()
  {
       $.post( "delete.php",$("#myForm2 :input").serialize(),function(info){ $("#result").html(info);});
  });
});

$("#myForm").submit( function() {
  return false; 
});
```

Comment: If you have to post a wall of code than you didn't try hard enough to debug this.

Comment: *sidenote:* you use the `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` libraries at the same time! why?

Comment: What does something like firebug say? Check the response of the request.

Comment: `mysql_query` in delete -> `mysqli_query($con, ...`

Comment: @scrowler changed that but still having same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple elements with the same ID `del`, since the input is created within an loop - when you use an id selector it will return only the first element with the given id so your click handler will get registered only to the first element. You can use class attribute to group similar elements instead of id.

change `<input name='del' id='del' type='button' value='Delete'>`  to

```
<input name='del' class='del' type='button' value='Delete'>
```

then use class selector to register the handler.

```
$('#del').click(function () {
    $.post("delete.php", $("#myForm2 :input").serialize(), function (info) {
        $("#result").html(info);
    });
});
```